# as.data.frame and cbind results in factor columns

Tags: r

I have a big data.frame with a mix of integer, character and strings columns. I'll need to order the data.frame by a numeric column.

When I combine the original columns into a data.frame all the columns change to factor, including the column I need for the sort.  So the sort gives something like `1, 10, 100...` instead of `1, 2, 3...`

Here is an example of my problem.

```
a <- 1:10
b <- c(1,3,5,6,2,10,100,110,7,4)
c <- LETTERS[1:10]
d <- as.data.frame(cbind(a, b, c))  # I am using this construction
e <- d[with(d, order(b)), ]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: try `d <- data.frame(a, b, c)`

Comment: I just found that form and tested. It works!. Post your comment as answer and Ill accept it.  Thanks

Comment: Where are people getting the notion that they should be using the data.frame(cbind(...)) construction ???!!!??? It is going to coerce all the vectors to character if there is a single character vector in the arguments (and as @TimP and kohske point out then it's going to turn them into factors.) There is an options() setting to change the default of stringsAsFactors to FALSE.

Comment: @DWin - Useful point about the option, but my preference is to be defensive and add the stringsAsFactors argument explicitly... it's way too easy for someone else to accidentally run the code (or a fragment of it) with the option not enabled correctly, and the time it takes to diagnose and fix the problem usually dwarfs the few seconds required to just add those few characters! :)

Comment: @DWin i don't know where everyone else gets it, but I absorbed by osmosis while learning R, and had to fight rather hard to get rid of it afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to do:

```
d <- data.frame(a, b, c, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The last part `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` prevents column `d$c` from being converted to factors. Include it, and your strings will stay as strings.

Don't forget `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` - it will save you untold misery, trust me!