# V-lookup style referencing in R without merging

Tags: r, vlookup

I have two tables. One with information on commissions payable for selling items on different websites. The other holding items which I would like to create a sale price for.

Please see both tables:

```
Channel <- c("DIRECT", "EBAY", "AMAZON")
Commission_percentage <- c(.1, .5, .4)
Min_commission <- c(0, 0, 2)
Processing <- c(0.05, 0.05, 0.03)

Commission_table <- as.data.frame(cbind(Channel, Commission_percentage, 
Min_commission, Processing))
```

The commissions table above shows commission percentages for each website, but shows that AMAZON will charge £2 minimum for each sale. It also shows another % charge for payment processing. The table below shows 5 items which are to be sold. It shows the website and also the amount paid for the item previously (cost).

```
Item <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5")
Cost <- c(10, 14, 18.85, 20, 5)    
Channel <- c("DIRECT", "EBAY", "AMAZON", "AMAZON", "AMAZON")

Price_table <- as.data.frame(cbind(Item, Cost, Channel))
```

I need to create a column for the Price_table which shows the "break-even" price for each item. I need to find the applicable commission charges depending on the channel on which the item is being sold, and for the Amazon items, I need to make sure that the minimum commission of £2 is charged if the standard commission percentage is calculated to be less than this.

To clarify, the break-even price needs to be;
Cost + max(commission_percentage * cost, min_commission)
 + (processing*(cost + max(commission_percentage * cost, min_commission)))

Ideally this needs to be memory efficient as the database is very, very large. Hence why I haven't just gone for a merge function and removed the extra columns once the price is calculated.

Many thanks,
Dan

Comment: [Jenny Bryan tweeted this, which is a start,](https://twitter.com/JennyBryan/status/980978609794895872) but I'm not sure it's going to help you out on memory.

Comment: Someone should have told you NEVER to use `as.data.frame(cbind(`. NEVER, NEVER, NEVER

Comment: @42- Would you mind explaining what the issue is with this? I'm fairly new to R and completely self-taught so I'm sure there's a million things I'm doing unefficiently! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you search google with "Why should I not use `as.data.frame(cbind(`" you find this as one of the early hits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924771/as-data-frame-and-cbind-results-in-factor-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's instead assume that these dataframe were constructed the *right* way.

```
Price_table <- data.frame( Item, Cost, Channel)
Commission_table <- data.frame(Channel, Commission_percentage, Min_commission, Processing)
```

If memory is limited, then perhaps you can use a `for`-loop which will not keep copying large portions of the dataframes:

```
befunc <- function( Cost, 
                   Commission_percentage, 
                   Min_commission,   Processing ) {
            Cost +
            max(Commission_percentage * Cost, Min_commission) + 
            Processing*(Cost + 
                              max(Commission_percentage * Cost, Min_commission))}

BE <- numeric(length(Price_table[['Channel']]))  #pre-allocation

 for ( Ch in seq_along(Price_table[['Channel']]) ){ 
    Cost =   Price_table[Ch, "Cost"]
    Chan <-  Price_table[Ch, "Channel"]; 
    CommPct <- Commission_table[ match(Chan,Commision_table[["Channel"]]), "Commission_percentage"]
    MinComm <- Commission_table[ match(Chan,Commision_table[["Channel"]]), "Min_commission"]
    Proc <-    Commission_table[ match(Chan,Commision_table[["Channel"]]), "Processing"]

 BE[Ch] <- befunc( Cost, CommPct, MinComm, Proc) }
```

That should allow garbage collection to occur when (or if) memory becomes limited.

Comment: Hi @42-, I'm unsure if I am doing something wrong here. If I cbind BE to Price_table, I get 15.75 break-even for item A1, however this should be;
10+max(10*0.10,0)+(0.05*(10+max(10*0.10,0))) => 11+0.55 = 11.55.

That being said, the answer for item A5 for example is correct.

Comment: Did you do it with your data or my correction? Just in case I added a `match` step in case a factor was being converted inappropriately.

Comment: I did it with your correction - I've just noticed that it's caused by the misspelling of "Commision" on the last few rows of the 'for' loop. After correcting the spelling the solution works perfectly. Thanks again.